# TypeError: addProductPaymentResponse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'paymentForOrderID'

Tags: python, reactjs, django

I want to restrict post request if similar str(number) in `paymentForOrderID` is already exists in `ProductPayment` model,

`#model.py`

```
class ProductPayment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, editable=False,verbose_name="Payment Made By",)
    paymentForOrderID = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Payment For Order ID")
    paymentMethodUsed = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True,editable=False, verbose_name="Method Used")
    aproxTimeAndDateOfPayment = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True,editable=False, verbose_name="Approx Date/Time Of Payment")
    totalAmountPaid = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True,editable=False, verbose_name="Amount Paid")
    paymentDetails = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,editable=False,verbose_name="Details")
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False, verbose_name="Entry ID")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.createdAt)
```

I'm trying this way.... `#views.py`

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def addProductPaymentResponse(request, paymentForOrderID):
    user = request.user
    data = request.data
    response_list = ProductPayment.objects.all()

    alreadyExists = response_list.objects.filter(paymentForOrderID=paymentForOrderID).exists()
    
    if alreadyExists:
        content = {'detail': 'Sorry Response has already been recieved'}
        return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        product = ProductPayment.objects.create(
                user=user,
                paymentForOrderID=data['paymentForOrderID'],
                paymentMethodUsed=data['paymentMethodUsed'],
                aproxTimeAndDateOfPayment=data['aproxTimeAndDateOfPayment'],
                totalAmountPaid=data['totalAmountPaid'],
                paymentDetails=data['paymentDetails'],
            )
        return Response('Payment Response added')
```

On hitting `post` action from frontend I get this error

```
TypeError: addProductPaymentResponse() missing 1 required positional argument: 'paymentForOrderID'
[22/Jul/2021 18:13:01] "POST /api/payments/product-payment-add-response/ HTTP/1.1" 500 102170
```

So kindly highlight where is the mistake and how can I fix that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you haven't set up the URL correctly. The URL you POST to should look something like `/api/payments/12345/product-payment-add-response/`, and in urls.py should look something like:

```py
path('/api/payments/<int:paymentForOrderID>/product-payment-add-response/', addProductPaymentResponse, name='payment-add-response')
```